# Numpy generate X random binary numbers with a define threshold in 1 line

Tags: python, numpy

I have come with the following code to generate an array of size: `arr_size`, containing only 1's and 0's so that, on average, it'll have "`threshold`" 1's in it.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
arr_size = 100
threshold = 0.18
rand_arr = np.random.random(arr_size)
result = np.where(rand_arr < threshold, 1, 0)
```

I'd like to know if numpy or python, in general, has a better way generate the desired array, preferably in 1 line.

Comment: This is called a binomial trial: `np.random.binomial(1, threshold, arr_size)`

Comment: Excellent! I've failed to find it myself. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @EliKorvigo checks out: `np.random.binomial(1, 0.234, (1000, 1000)).sum(axis=0).mean()/1000
# --> 0.234018`

Comment: @FHTMitchell ha ha ha ;]

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'm not sure I fully understand your implications. Do you mean the ratio you get in the end is not exactly equal to the parameter? If that is the case, then this is what you get with random number generation: sample mean only converges to the expectation in the limit.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I think he was kidding with you